# Error con strtotime. Versión de PHP 5.4.16

Tags: php

Me aparece este error al usar la funcion strtotime:

> exception 'ErrorException' with message 'strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.

El código en el que me da error es este:

```
//Fecha viene asi: yyyy-mm-dd
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES');
$mes = strftime("%B", strtotime($fecha));

$mes .= " de " . $year;

return $mes;
```

Hay alguna alternativa a `strtotime` porque también lo uso en otras funciones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El mensaje te está diciendo que debes configurar en tu `php.ini` la franja horaria añadiendo esta línea ([más zonas](http://php.net/timezones)):

```
date.timezone = Europe/Madrid
```

O bien que en tu código uses (al igual que has usado `setlocale`) la función [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set) de la siguiente manera:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
```

De modo que tu código quedaría:

```
$fecha = '2016-12-31';
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES', 'es');
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
$time = strtotime($fecha);
$año = strftime("%Y", $time);
$mes = strftime('%B', $time);

$mes .= " de " . $año;

echo "$mes\n";
```

Con eso debería dejar de lanzarte ese mensaje de advertencia.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que configurar el parámetro `date.timezone` en tu php.ini o ejecutar la función `date_default_timezone_set()` antes que una función de fecha/hora.

Busca dicho parámetro en tu php.ini y aplícale un valor, por ejemplo `Europe/Madrid`, aquí puedes ver el [listado completo de zonas horarias](http://php.net/manual/es/timezones.php) disponible, o ejecuta la función usando uno de esos valores.

Comment: Te me adelantaste por extenderme en enlaces y código :)

Comment: @OscarGarcia, lo bueno, si breve, dos veces bueno. No obstante tu respuesta es excelente.